# command line or batch file to get the name of the computer and find and replace serverName with the computer name in a text file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command

command line or batch file to get the "name of the computer" and find and replace "serverName" in a text file with the "computer name" in a text file?

Comment: Is serverName the only line in your text file? How does serverName correspond with the computer name? You really need to explain yourself better, you've left out a lot of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting hostname is easy.  Either use hostname.exe like so:

```
$hostname = hostname.exe
```

Or WMI:

```
$hostname = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
```

Replacing text in a file usually amounts to something like this:

```
$content = Get-Content file.txt
$content | Foreach {$_ -replace "serverName",$hostname} | Out-File file.txt -Enc ascii
```

The `$_` above will represent each line of the file.  That's because $content will contain an array of lines that will get fed down the pipeline one line at a time.